# I can't create an overlay from a calendar on my main site

Tags: calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I can't seem to add an overlay for a calendar from my main site. I have a site (companyname.com) and several department subsites, and both the main site and each department subsite has a calendar. When I enter the URL to resolve a subsite for any calendar overlay (eg - https://companyname.com/billing) it works and I can select a list and a view. This works whether I am creating an overlay from the main site calendar or any of the subsite calendars. But when I try to resolve the address for the main site nothing seems to work. I have tried the site url, /lists, the full url of the calendar, and nothing seems to work.

For reference, the calendar is an app on the main site. It is called Company Calendar. There are no special permissions or anything, and all other calendars are built in the same way but on subsites.

Comment: when you enter `https://mainsiturl` and hit `Resolve` button what happens?

Comment: I get red text that says "Cannot complete this action. Please try again."

Comment: Can you check the sharepoint log files.. that might give some hint

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can contact the administrator.. because the log files are located on the SharePoint server filesystem

Comment: You're trying to overlay the calendar on itself?

Comment: Yes. I'm attempting to do something similar to this: http://summit7systems.com/color-code-calendar-events-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score -1):

Create a new view for your main calendar. Otherwise it will not work.

[image: Create a new calendar view]

[image: Don't forget to choose Calendar View]